# C# Blazor: How to use @typeparam in Code behind? (with workaround)

Tags: c#, blazor

In a Blazor **.razor** file you can use `@typeparam MyType` to use **generic parameters**.
For example:

**MyComponent.razor**

```
@typeparam MyType

<SomeHtml />

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public List<MyType> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

So you can call:

```
<MyComponent MyType="MyTypeABC" MyList="@MyData.MyList" />
```

But I prefer code behind (razor.cs), how can I use a parameter for type like `@typeparam MyType` in the razor.cs file?

My current **workaround** is:

**MyComponent.razor**

```
@inherits MyComponentCode<MyType>
@typeparam MyType
```

**MyComponent.razor.cs**

```
public class MyComponentCode<MyType> : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public List<MyType> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

I miss something like `[TypeParameter]`, but maybe there are better solutions, any ideas? Or maybe it's a general question about "how to use razor @statements in a code behind".

---

***Update from 2020-02-27:***

With suggestion from **Roger Wolf** (see below), a bit better way:

**MyComponent.razor**

```
@typeparam MyType
```

**MyComponent.razor.cs**

```
public partial class MyComponent<MyType>
{
    [Parameter]
    public List<MyType> MyList{ get; set; }
}
```

**Call**

```
<MyComponent MyType="MyTypeABC" />
```

Answer (score 25):

You were pretty close, just need to add `partial` to the class definition:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp1.Components
{
    public partial class MyCustomComponent<T> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Razor part:

```
@namespace BlazorApp1.Components
@typeparam T

<label>@($"{Label}. Provided type is {typeof(T).Name.ToUpper()}")</label>
```

The usage (Index.razor):

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp1.Components

<MyCustomComponent T="long" Label="Custom component label" />
```

This way, you wouldn't need inheriting your component from it, as both become parts of the same class.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for (typeparam in .cs file), but yes `partial class MyComponent` is just better than `@inherits MyComponent`.
In this case you can also remove the inheritance of the ComponentBase (`: ComponentBase`), because the Component itself is already a ComponentBase ;), which means you can still use methods like `protected override void OnInitialized()`.