# C# Blazor: How to use a dynamic @typeparam in Code behind?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I would like to know, how it is possible to call a component with a `@typeparam` which comes from the URL

As it has been already discussed in [C# Blazor: How to use @typeparam in Code behind? (with workaround)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393496/c-sharp-blazor-how-to-use-typeparam-in-code-behind-with-workaround), I built a component like Roger Wolf did in his solution.

**Raozor.cs**
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

```
namespace BlazorApp1.Components
{
    public partial class MyCustomComponent<T> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Razor part:**

```
@namespace BlazorApp1.Components
@typeparam T
<label>@($"{Label}. Provided type is {typeof(T).Name.ToUpper()}")</label>
```

**Index.razor page**

```
@page "/{typeName}"
@using BlazorApp1.Components

<MyCustomComponent T="@TypeName" Label="Custom component label" />
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string TypeName {get; set;}
}
```

So the Line where I try to set the Type by the string property I get en compiler error. (I guess that internal an typeof() function will determine the type for the component class.)
It will only compile, if I use an fixed coded type. :

```
e.g.: <MyCustomComponent T="long" Label="Custom component label" />
```

What I want to do is pull the type parameter from URL. Any ideas to get this work?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `@typeparam` is deduce at compile time and you should have a parameter of type `T` in your component:

```cs
namespace BlazorApp1.Components
{
    public partial class MyCustomComponent<T> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public T MyParameter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It's use to make generic component, you cannot use it as your sample.