# Mapping Model class to its Razor Component

Tags: razor, blazor, razor-components

I am learning Blazor currently.

My model has a abstract class and a dozen concrete implementations of this abstract class.
For example `Fruit` and `Apple`, `Banana` and `Orange`.
Each implementation needs a specific user interface.

So I created a Razor Component for each class. Let's call them `AppleView`, `BananaView` and `OrangeView`.

My frontend queries a `Fruit[]` and loops through each entry and renders the specific Razor Component. Looks like this:

```
@foreach (Fruit fruit in Fruites)
{
    if (fruit is Apple apple)
        <AppleView fuit="apple" />
    else if (fruit is Banana banana)
        <BananaView fuit="banana" />
    else if (fruit is Orange orange)
        <OrangeView fuit="orange" />
}
```

Is there a better way of weaving together such a big if-else-statement? Is there a way of mapping a model class to its view?

Thanks!

Comment: You may use Templated Components to create generic typed components...

Comment: If this is the only place you do this then this is fine. If you need to do it in multiple places then create a component `<FruitView>` which takes the instance as a `[Parameter]` decorated property and uses the above code to select the specific component.

Comment: You can use generics in components, as demonstrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60410766